# Problem in converting from html to pdf

Tags: php, html, pdf

I'm currently on a php project in which the pdf files can be able download generated from (html content) server side backend. I've already tested **html2pdf librairy** and I've found it is not a right choice for me because it doesn't support **utf-8 format**. When I tried with **utf8_decode()**, described in their documentation, the problem is just the same, showing a series of unknown characters. The language used is "Myanmar".

So I really would like to know if there's another good php based libraries for converting to pdf format.

Thanks in advance

Mee Mee

Answer (score 0):

Try TCPDF.

http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf_examples

Main Features:

```
* no external libraries are required for the basic functions;
* supports all ISO page formats;
* supports custom page formats, margins and units of measure;
* supports UTF-8 Unicode and Right-To-Left languages;
* supports TrueTypeUnicode, OpenTypeUnicode, TrueType, OpenType, Type1 and CID-0 fonts;
* supports document encryption;
* includes methods to publish some (x)HTML code;
```

[and many more ..](http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf)

Answer (score 0):

Try: "[wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)" it just work great (and its -open source-). It uses **webkit** engine (used by safari, chrome browsers) and it is very easy to use. It also supports UTF-8:

```
wkhtmltopdf stackoverflow.com/questions/1164140/ output.pdf
```

Try it! for Linux and Windows as well. Easy to install. If you use ubuntu, type:

```
aptitude install wkhtmltopdf
```

I guess you need to have some fonts to support "Myanmar", as It was not able to display the language in my browser (with UTF-8).